# Linux procfs system information api

Tags: c, linux, monitoring

I am writing one tool and I need to gather some information about running Linux system beyond those that available from `sysinfo`, as I understand many of them are available from `/proc/` file system, but I need to do it from the C language level, is there any system API for doing this or maybe I should just write functions or scripts that do it for me and pass results to my C program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`proc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) filesystem *is* the API: you read the pseudo-files to get the data. This can be done in any programming language, including C.

Comment: I know I can do it from C, but I think that parsing such a file would be easier in something like Python, and then pass the results that I am interested in to C program.

Comment: @Andna: This is also possible. It's up to you to decide which makes more sense in your setting.